# Attribute of label not working in angular directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to learn how to work with angular directives and so far with success. I have only one minor issue I cannot figure out.

In my directive I got a for attribute set on the same value of the id of an input field. But clicking on the label doesn't give the input control the focus like it should work normally.

I got this issue worked out in some example code:

```
<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='testCtrl'>
    <label for="test1">Testlabel 1</label><br>
    <input id="test1" type="text"></input><br>
    <my-input id="test2" 
              label="Testlabel 2" 
              placeholder="enter somthing"
              text="testVar"></my-input><br>
    <span>{{testVar}}</span>
</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
angular.module('test', [])
.directive('myInput', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<label for={{id}}>{{label}}</label><br>' +
                  '<input id={{id}} type="text" ' +
                  ' placeholder={{placeholder}} ng-model="text" />',
        scope: {
            id: "@",
            label: "@",
            placeholder: "@",
            text: "="
        }
   }
})
.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.testVar = 'testing';
}]);
```

Same code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U92em/

What mistake am I making which causes my problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Meaning if you click on label "Testlabel2" the input control under the label is getting the focus? I test it in the latest version of chrome and IE and both the input doesn't get the focus. Testing it in windows 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "wrapper" has the same `id` too and it is not good. You can remove it in a `link` function, this way:

```
 link: function(scope,el,attrs){
     el.removeAttr("id");
 }
```

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/5u4Xp/

Or in `compile` function (thanks to [Florent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1466682/florent)):

```
 compile: function(el){
     el.removeAttr("id")
 }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/7GG6k/

Comment: `compile` looks better to me.

Comment: @Florent you're 100% right!  if you'll want to post it as yours , i'll remove  it from my answer

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler just to change the id of the input like `id="{{id}}_input"` in the directive's template?

Comment: @blesh yes , but we are not looking for an easy ways! :))

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. Although I don't understand why `replace: true` isn't removing the wrapper code and also removing the id that is causing the problem. But adding the compile function solves the problme as well.