# Label for not working in angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using this custom template inside a directive to generate customized input fields with associated labels:

```
template: function(elem, attrs) {
        var elemTpl =   '<div> ' +
                            '<div class="form-group col-md-{{cols}}" >' +
                                '<label for="{{id}}" class="control-label input-sm">{{text}}</label> ' +
                                '<input type="{{type}}" ng-model="value" name="' + attrs.id + '" id="' + attrs.id +
                                '" class="form-control input-sm szpFocusable" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-required="required" spellcheck="false"/>' +
                            '</div> ' +
                        '</div>';

        return elemTpl;
    }
```

The problem is that when the label is clicked, the input field is not being focused. When moving the code outside the directive and putting the input tags directly in the html, all works fine. The id and the name attributes are bound correctly to the appropriate scope fields.

Comment: are you sure {{id}} is the same as attrs.id ? check the generated html with firebug (or other developer tool)

Comment: 100% sure. Checked it with chrome's developer tool.

Comment: Any chance that id is not unique?

Comment: And why not the same methods for id? name="{{id}}" instead of attrs.id ? (Just trying something now your code is somewhat limited, I can't see where attrs come from for example)

Comment: @Michiel You're right. The enclosing directive tag had an id exactly the same as the input tag. I did a replace: true on the directive, but the enclosing div is still there??? Never mind, that I'll figure out. If you formulate your comment as an answer, I'll accept is as the correct answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure the ID you are using is unique?

Another option is to nest the `<input>` tag in the `<label>`, in that case you don't need the `for` argument:

```
   var elemTpl = '<div> ' +
        '<div class="form-group col-md-{{cols}}" >' +
        '<label class="control-label input-sm">{{text}}' +
           '<input type="{{type}}" ng-model="value" name="' + attrs.id + '" id="' + attrs.id + '" class="form-control input-sm szpFocusable" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-required="required" spellcheck="false"/>' + 
        '</label>' +
        '</div> ' +
      '</div>';
```

**Note**: 
The real answer is in the 2nd comment below: In a directive the content of element template is placed within the directive tag, in this case resulting in the id being used twice. This can be solved by adding `replace : true` to the return value of the directive.
This will replace your directive tag with the contents of your template.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
      replace: 'true',
      template: templateThatUsesId
  };
});
```

Comment: One funny thing I already said is that with replace set to true in the directive, the enclosing directive tag is removed, but all the attributes are moved to the next html tag, "div" in my case. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Never mind, read the documentation now, it says: replace the current element with the contents of the HTML. The replacement process migrates all of the attributes / classes from the old element to the new one. See the Creating Components section below for more information.

Comment: @zszep, Thanks for that last comment, I finally understand now too :-) Definitely helpfull!

Comment: I had a similar problem, was trying to create dynamic id as well as a dynamic label and somewhere something wasn't working. But wrapping the labels around the input releaved me of the headache! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here there is a more accurate answer:
[Attribute of label not working in angular directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329818/attribute-of-label-not-working-in-angular-directive)

When rendering directives with templates the container has the same id than the checkbox:

```
<div class="color-warning checkbox ng-isolate-scope ng-valid" ng-model="ckeck4" id="kitten>
<input id="kitten" type="checkbox">
<label for="kitten">CUSTOM LABEL</label>
</div>
```

The div that wrappers the rendered directive and the checkbox have the same id, not quite good.

In order to delete it we use a link function:

```
link: function(scope,el,attrs){
    el.removeAttr("id")
}
```

This is because the link function is executed before angular renders the directive, so, we are removin the id from the div that wrappers the directive, here there is my complete code:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('planetCheckbox', [])
    .controller('PlanetCheckboxController', PlanetCheckboxController)
    .directive('checkbox', DirectiveCheckbox);

    function DirectiveCheckbox() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
                classes: '@class',
                customLabel: '@',
                check: '=',
                id:'@'//,
                //radio :'@'
            },
            link: function(scope,el,attrs){
                el.removeAttr("id")
            },
            controller: 'PlanetCheckboxController',
            templateUrl: 'planet-checkbox/template.html'
        }
    };

    PlanetCheckboxController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function PlanetCheckboxController($scope) {
        $scope.ngModel = $scope.check;
    };

    angular.module('planetCheckbox')
        .run(['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
        $templateCache.put('planet-checkbox/template.html', '<div class="checkbox">'+

            '<input id="{{id}}" type="checkbox" />' +
            '<label for="{{id}}">CUSTOM LABEL</label>' +
        '</div>'



        );
    }]);
})();
```

The living example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/5u4Xp/

Answer (score 1):

Label for is working for id and not for name

```
<label for="idxyz" class="control-label input-sm">{{text}}</label> 
<input  id="idxyz" type="{{type}}" ng-model="value" .....
```

It always works for me!

Comment: As I stated in my comment, the id and the name are the same. The problem was that the label and input element were in a directive and in the way directives function: "replace the current element with the contents of the HTML. The replacement process migrates all of the attributes / classes from the old element to the new one"

Comment: name="' + attrs.id + '" id="' + attrs.id + '"  so in your for use the same logic say for = "' + attrs.id + '", and 100% sure it will work.